# Angular Create Dynamic year dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a year selection dropdown. year must start from this year upto next 7 years .

I have tried

```
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var range = [];

range.push(year);

for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    range.push(year + i);
}

$scope.years = range;

<select class="form-control"  ng-options="year for year in years" name="expiryMonth" ng-model="expiryMonth" required>'
```

But this creates a html ,

```
<option label="2016" value="number:2016">2016</option>
```

this creates a required year dropdown
But i want Value to be last two digits of label

Also, my first option should be like

```
<option value="">select month</option>
```

Comment: Don't understand. Value of your model is the same as label. See this Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/ygxpfIlheIhGE8MvUIIR?p=preview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller("Ctrl",
    function contactListCtrl($scope) {

       var year = new Date().getFullYear();
    var range = [];
    range.push(year);
    for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        range.push(year + i);
    }
    $scope.years = range;


    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.9" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="Ctrl">

<select class="form-control" ng-model="expiryMonth" required>
  <option>Select month</option>
  <option ng-repeat="year in years">{{year}}</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want that value will be only last two digits of label you can extend your `years` object like:

```
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var range = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    range.push({
      label: year + i,
      value: parseInt(String(year + i).slice(2, 4))
    });
}

$scope.years = range;
```

And `ng-options` like:

`ng-options="year.value as year.label for year in years"`

See this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jxraYbDoA4lXrG30tv75?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a useful dynamic year range.

```js
let years: number[] = [];
let currentYear: number = new Date().getFullYear();
for(let i = (currentYear - 7); i < (currentYear + 7); i++) {
    years.push(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using ng-repeat to create your `<option>`

```
<select class="form-control" name="expiryMonth" ng-model="expiryMonth" required>
    <option value="">select month</option>
    <option ng-repeat="year in years" value="{{year}}">{{year}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It is recommended to use ng-options actually.

Comment: 1. I never said anywhere that ng-repeat is recommended over ng-options 2. Why over complicate your code just to use recommended functionality...

Answer (score 0):

For dates and times in angular i often use:

'uib-datepicker'

More information:
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

In this directive you can use 'min-date'

```
 <input type="text" starting-day="0"  uib-datepicker="{{format}}" ng-model="vm.dateFrom" is-open="true" min-date="vm.minDate" max-date="vm.dateTo"  />
```

And in your controller:

```
vm.minDate = yourFunctionToDate()
```

Answer (score 0):

I made you a [**fiddle that you can find here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/12453/)

Basically, use the expression `track by` to give the value you want to your options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<select ng-model="expiryMonth">
    <option ng-repeat="year in years" value="{{year}}">{{year}}</option>
</select>
```